# Hibernate ManyToMany with CascadeType.PERSIST deletes related enteties

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "virus_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "capital_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<Capital> capitals;
```

I have a many to many mapping table with `CascadeType.PERSIST` and when i do a delete query hibernate removes all of the capitals from the capital table as well. Why is it doing that? how to stop it.
And in the same time when i save this entity i want the mapping table to be populated

Comment: How do you issue the delete? em.remove()?

Comment: hey, i use spring data, witch extends hibernate, and i found the solution, it tuned out if i am using manytomany i don't need any cascade